# Ldap socket option - ldapjs

Tags: node.js, sockets, ldap, ldapjs

I am trying to connect to an LDAP server from my node.js application using ldapjs module. I'm following the [documentation](http://ldapjs.org/client.html).

I would like to know more about the `socketPath` option and when it has to be used. I would also like to know how to add the `socketPath` to the `createClient` option. There's hardly any info about this on web.

I think the server is on UNIX domain socket. Not sure, want to test it.

Also, Please help me how to construct the socket path with port number as a single string.

Comment: Unless your LDAP server uses UNIX domain sockets you don't red to know anything about it at all.

Comment: @user207421I probably need to use it. I guess it's on UNIX socket. Not sure, but want to test it out.